# Sending a url by email that opens in specific browser

Tags: browser, shortcuts, hyperlink

I'm sending an email with a link to a website that works best in Google Chrome. Is there a way to make the link open in Chrome (if the recipient has it installed) instead of their default browser?

I know you can create shortcuts on the Desktop that open a specific site with a specific browser, but can such a shortcut be simply sent by email for it to work on the recipients PC?

Or if this is not possible, can the link force an "open with…" dialog box to open?

Comment: The problem with Chrome, is that it is installed in the user profile, and not on a default location such as Program Files. You can try modifying the shortcut to `%localappdata%\chrome...` but if the user has no chrome, they will get an error rather than it going by their default browser. It is far easier to just type in the email to open this with Chrome or similar. Note new MS Edge uses the Chrome engine, and so do many other browsers too, such as Vivaldi, Opera, Chromium, etc...

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible. But you could include a small description in the email body for the recipients to use Google Chrome when clicking the link.

Comment: That is what I'm doing now, but some people that are not familiar with technology don't even know what a browser is, so I was trying to simplify it for them since most of them would have Chrome installed (by someone else).